# Can padding of bases or [[no_unique_address]] members be used to store other bases/members?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The note in [`[dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr#note-1) says:

> [Note 1: The non-static data member can share the address of another non-static data member or that of a base class, and any **padding that would normally be inserted at the end of the object can be reused as storage for other members**.
> — end note]

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

Since the only normative effect of `no_unique_address` is making the object *potentially-overlapping*, which base classes automatically are, the same effects should apply to base classes.

This appears to contradict [`[intro.object]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#9)

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies.
> Two objects with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or **if at least one is a subobject of zero size** and they are of different types; **otherwise, they** have distinct addresses and **occupy disjoint bytes of storage**.

This seemingly permits overlap only if one of the objects is zero-size (is potentially-overlapping and empty).

And indeed, neither GCC, Clang, nor MSVC allow non-empty objects to overlap: <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BXIFVNQJ1DQTFkTFxibb1jc25bcM9faXliQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANQAgiYaBwDsVkc7FzthBDuqJv5ne5c7CggkNwCe948mxwAi30OByOGy2ux%2BpyBz1e7x20UBR1%2BAIeQKBoO2NzcOxA%2B1IOwsO1%2BVn%2BCOBe3RuwBiMh50uJgArFZGQxUAB9LwMPAARy8mFZTHQ6GImAUCgZAPpf32OyYpOeDKZFhZ7M5PL5AqFIrFkvF%2BLhpKRBqOAHpjTsACpvJQy0VxRwCBQ7ZJMUV46JeG4ASR2mFUyWqBEw6B2BAQmBeeAAXuGiHDwyYAGwadLR1BUCDXOY7ABUOzMiY0VwYG0wAoAdGj6o5kPzbY0ICnMGmIG4s/dkVLG83Mzmdv45qSNkxq7WlPWu%2Bm/m3/B2I6n0z3c/3SRwFrROPTeH4OFpSKhOG5rNYXksVvGzP4eKQCJpVwsANYgekafScSRb297zi8BQgF83ndV1IOBYBgRAUFQFhkjoOJyEoNAoJg%2BJgC4MwuD4OhA2IX8IGiT9ojCBoPk4K8ELYQQAHkGFoYjANILAWEMYBxDo/BhRqAA3EVP19aoPTWK9rkwdc6NoPBomIIiPCwT9NjwFgSKAqgDGABQADU8EwAB3Cj/W3K9%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUOjdECAwjBQI9LH0cTf0gBZUGSe1i04ABaDZ0HbUxLGsMxC18gB1MRaB2SLfU2JhYv9dBDGrXy4mIEgFB/YSA0yFwGHcTwWj0EIwn6MpBnQ1J0m8sZWnyWrMmmAZ4nQjpvO6UZivGWxcs6Bgut6cqZiqyZupyBqh0aFrKrahYFFPVY9E2TABKAkTN1Ibdd33DhVAADgTXyE0kHZgGQZAdlQssuB2FsnJsHZcEIEhCQvdCdg8RD6GId7/H7XgAK0OYFjDAVBggNc314BT/DMMt6QSfxJA0FGNAOg7jg0DQE22z89p/P9r1vBYQPAhDoN%2BuCIEppCUHslDUZfGhaCwnC8LogjmGIWjSMg8iCComjPwYpiWN3Ni8q4386N45B%2BMU8hBGEz8xIkqSMDWXc5IU7glJU9TNJ0vSlcM4RRHEMzzcstRP10Mx9CYxyQuc9W3KhvcvMyWX/IIQKZ2CqxLDC2KotoGK4tUBKkqDVK8GQdLiEy7CcvsbyCqKybSsK2bZmqgo6p6hqasKBg87GjrahGJpi70Kuuhriu2vG2vs/apuRtaiQFqW0zr2FdboY4Ladt4PbDuO06dmQRnrskMsNEX%2B7D1dp6XqIP7zEvPFvqpuJ/rMOYgdJsHSyweJPZE99SAUswDtuhMDoSJHn2ONCUaSMevw4In/1J4CYEIBIDptTCgtNIL73iBxZAyRkisg4lwBIrIDCBg2KyVQp0MJsziBzfChFeZKzIowIW1FaKS0wIxIwEteBS04txOWqg%2BKBiVkJESu51aSV5tJbWQNiDyUUgsZSTBVIaW0rpRgZtZDGSttIG2Sg7Y2T0IzF2wcbDu3gB5b2DpODGgCqo6wqCRQEDTnlZwEBXD1RzugZuehS5F3bo1Mutj2r9U6jXKxrj07VymF3Oa9cPF1w7r4ko3cuC92WMtdCq0h6vhHh%2BOiE9p4sAUDAnYiCEhliMRsFej08QbzetvT6e8kL/XCSfQCoNSDgwvpQYeN84aZIvMcBM/hsYHX8AkLgp16TSG/oTWwxNgZ3lII%2BZ8cT/AJN2t%2BEmlTh5mCmePGZwyqlcWwvlSQQA)</kbd>

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    short y;
};

struct B
{
    short b;
};

struct C : A, B {};

struct D
{
    [[no_unique_address]] A a;
    [[no_unique_address]] B b;
};

// Those assertions pass, but I expected the size to be `sizeof(int) * 2` instead.
static_assert(sizeof(C) == sizeof(int) * 3);
static_assert(sizeof(D) == sizeof(int) * 3);
```

There's also [`[basic.types.general]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#2) that governs memcpy-ing trivially copyable types:

> For any object (**other than a potentially-overlapping subobject**) of trivially copyable type `T`, ... the underlying bytes ... can be copied into an array of `char` ...

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

If only empty objects can overlap, then it's unclear why it bans all potentially-overlapping objects and not only the empty ones.

What's going on here? Can non-empty potentially-overlapping objects actually overlap, and is there a way to make compilers do so without extensions?

---

Found the [proposal that added `[[no_unique_address]]`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0840r2.html). The plot thickens:

> Does this allow reuse of tail padding?
>
> Tail padding reuse is permitted for base classes, so it's also permitted for members with the attribute.

And the "disjoint bytes of storage" part was added by this very proposal, and didn't exist before. A regression perhaps?

Comment: I think I'll remove the C++20 tag, since I don't want to restrict the answers to it.

Comment: You asked about a C++20 feature. And the "potentially-overlapping" wording is *specific* to C++20; it did not exist in pre-C++20 versions. Any answer *must* be restricted to C++20.

Comment: @NicolBolas Those version tags are a tad ambiguous. On one hand this is a C++20 change, but on the other I prefer an answer from the latest draft, not from C++20 (the difference will matter more once more standards are released).

Comment: Unless C++ stops being backwards compatible, or a change is made that affects the wording, C++YY tags also include all later versions. And if a change *is* made that changes wording, then your question would still not apply to it. It's a C++20 and any later applicable version question.

Comment: I'd want to update this Q&A if the wording ever changes. But ok, added the tag back.

Comment: Your MSVC test is sort of insufficient, by the way, since `no_unique_address` is a no-op on MSVC for ABI compatibility reasons - they support `msvc::no_unique_address` if you want the same support under MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially-overlapping subobjects can overlap. What *cannot* happen is overlap between two potentially-overlapping subobjects if neither of them has zero size. That's what [intro.object]/9 is saying.

That is, `D::a` is potentially overlapping, but it cannot overlap with `D::b`. If there were a hypothetical `D::empty_class` that was also potentially overlapping, then `D::a` could actually overlap with it.

"Potentially overlapping" is only "potentially"; whether any *actual* overlap happens with any other potentially overlapping object depends on the circumstances.

> But then what's the difference between non-empty PO and non-PO?

The difference is *intent*.

Since the benefit of `no_unique_address` only appears if the type in question is empty, why even allow the attribute on non-empty types?

Because your code may not *know* if a type is empty. That type could be provided to your class by the user as a template parameter (the `allocator` given to containers, for example). You wouldn't want your code to break just because the user provided a non-empty type. What you want is to take advantage of the case when the user *does* provide an empty type.

Plus, there's the fact that what constitutes an "empty type" is actually somewhat implementation-dependent. So some compilers may give you the optimization while others do not.

As such, provisions must be made for POs that are not zero-sized. Since the intent of declaring a subobject to be `no_unique_address` is that you will treat it as if it were overlapping (even if it doesn't happen to), the prohibition on using them in trivial copies merely holds you to your stated intent.

Comment: Yeah, but can't empty objects already overlap with anything? Not just with potentially-overlapping objects? If yes, then I don't get the difference between potentially-overlapping non-empty objects and non-potentially-overlapping objects.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*but can't empty object already overlap with anything?*" ... no. This is literally what `no_unique_address` is for. Pre-C++20, empty *base classes* could overlap under certain circumstances (required in standard layout types), but not empty subobjects in general.

Comment: I meant empty potentially-overlapping objects, sorry. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zG7Tqreqx

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: They can only do so *because of* the text you've quoted. I don't understand what you're getting at here.

Comment: Here's what I'm saying: Empty potentially-overlapping object (will shorten to PO) can overlap *any* object. Your answer says they can overlap non-empty PO (which is a weaker statement than the above). But then what's the difference between non-empty PO and non-PO? If both can be overlapped by empty POs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I've updated the answer to explain this.

Comment: *"The difference is intent."* But then [the note](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr#note-1) has to be wrong? It says trailing padding can be reused for storage of other members, which isn't the case if you're correct (unless you count the single byte of an empty object as a "trailing padding").

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*unless you count the single byte of an empty object as a "trailing padding"*" Why wouldn't you? Also, it's a non-normative note; the whole point of which is that they're explaining things in more informal language. The note is still correct; "can be reused" does not mean "will definitely be reused".

Comment: Of course it counts, but the note is worded in a way that *heavily implies* that it applies to any trailing padding, not just the single byte of empty PO objects. I propose adding a big fat "the note is misleading" at the begining of the answer. :) (it's getting late, I'll return to this tomorrow)

Comment: Apparently [P0840R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0840r2.html) was written under assumption that non-empty POs can overlap other non-empty objects, see question edit. Hmm.